# Scrapy - new instance of Item Pipeline classes per process/job?

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I use Scrapyd for scheduling and launching spider jobs.

In Item Pipelines classes i set job specific variables into the class, which should not be shared by other spiders/jobs.

So my question is, does Scrapy/Scrapyd create new instance of pipeline class for each spider job/process?

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy/Scrapyd create new instance of pipelines, middlewares, etc for each job/process.

Hovewer your pipelines must not have static(or per class variables) on some conditions data can be accessed from other spider via [python class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68672/10884791).

Comment: Under what conditions?

Comment: If your will store data inside pipeline class variable